# Pedagogical way of programming hierarchical clustering algorithm in R

Tags: r, algorithm, data-manipulation, hierarchical-clustering

I am preparing a lecture on machine learning in R and I want to take [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) as one example. I found this very instructive page here: http://home.deib.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/hierarchical.html

It starts with the following distance table (mind the `NA` as column/row name when reading in the data, see also below):

[image]

The shortest distance is `138` between `MI` and `TO`, so we want to merge those columns and rows to a new column/row `MI/TO` The distances of this new compound object `MI/TO` to all the remaining cities is equal to the shortest distance of one of the original cities `MI` or `TO`, so e.g. `MI/TO` to `RM` is `564` (from `MI`) because this shorter than `669` (from `TO`). (This way of doing the aggregation is called [single-linkage clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-linkage_clustering)). So we have a new table:

[image]

**My question**
I started coding this in R and soon found that the code is getting more and more messy - far from something that can be easily understood by fledgling programmers. Do you know an approach or a package with which you can do this kind of data manipulation in a natural and intuitive way?

---

So here is the starting table in R:

```
D <- matrix(c(0,662,877,255,412,996,
              662,0,295,468,268,400,
              877,295,0,754,564,138,
              255,468,754,0,219,869,
              412,268,564,219,0,669,
              996,400,138,869,669,0), ncol=6, byrow=T)

rownames(D) <- colnames(D) <- c("BA","FI","MI","Na","RM","TO")

D
##     BA  FI  MI  Na  RM  TO
## BA   0 662 877 255 412 996
## FI 662   0 295 468 268 400
## MI 877 295   0 754 564 138
## Na 255 468 754   0 219 869
## RM 412 268 564 219   0 669
## TO 996 400 138 869 669   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in function "hclust" is already a nice function to work with.

```
hc1 = hclust(as.dist(D), method = "single")
hc1$merge
plot(hc1)
```

I can describe in details if you want a clarification.

Following the logic of the hclust, you can try:

```
savemat = list()
D1 = D; diag(D1) = Inf # a trick to make zero a infinity
m = 1
while(dim(D1)[1] > 2) {
    # get the location of minimum distance
    minloc = which(D1 == min(D1), arr.ind = T)[1,]
    # make a two-column matrix then find out the minimum value of each row
    u = apply(cbind(D1[minloc[2],],D1[minloc[1],]),1,min)
    # updating the matrix
    D1[minloc[2],] = u 
    D1[,minloc[2]] = u
    u = paste0(rownames(D1)[minloc[2]],'/',rownames(D1)[minloc[1]])
    rownames(D1)[minloc[2]] = u
    colnames(D1)[minloc[2]] = u
    # deleting the merged column/row
    D1 = D1[-minloc[1],-minloc[1]]
    diag(D1) = Inf
    # save the steps into a list element mth
    savemat[[m]] = D1
    m = m + 1
}
savemat
```

Comment: I know this function but my question is about programming this example from scratch!

Comment: +1: This is impressive, I will analyse your code in detail. I don't want to ask too much but is there an easy way to take the case into account when some distances appear more than once? This would result in new clusters with more than one city added at once. Another thing is: How would you print the resulting hierarchy (basically the dendrogram)? In any case: Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 2):

Updated code as a recursive function and a separate printing function to allow a better following of what's going on. Use with `hcl(<data.frame>,<log_level>)`. Log level can be 0 for just the final result, 1 to print intermediate datasets and 2 to print each steps

```
# To be allowed to add column later, don't know a better way than coercing to data.frame
d <- data.frame(D,stringsAsFactors=F) 

myprt <- function(message,var) {
  print(message)
  print(var)
}

hcl <- function(d,prt=0) {
  if (prt) myprt("Starting dataset:",d)

  # 1) Get the shortest distance informations:
  Ref <- which( d==min(d[d>0]), useNames=T, arr.ind=T ) 
  if (prt>1) myprt("Ref is:",Ref)
  # 2) Subset the original entry to remove thoose towns:
  res <- d[-Ref[,1],-Ref[,1]]
  if (prt>1) myprt("Res is:", res)

  # 3) Get the subset for the two nearest towns:
  tmp <- d[-Ref[,1],Ref[,1]]
  if (prt>1) myprt("Tmp is:",tmp)

  # 4) Get the vector of minimal distance from original dataset with the two town (row by row on t)
  dists <- apply( tmp, 1, function(x) { x[x==min(x)] } )
  #dists <- tmp[ tmp == pmin( tmp[,1], tmp[,2] ) ]
  if (prt>1) myprt("Dists is:",dists)

  # 5) Let's build the resulting matrix:
  tnames <- paste(rownames(Ref),collapse="/") # Get the names of town to the new name
  if (length(res) == 1) {

    # Nothing left in the original dataset just concat the names and return
    tnames <- paste(c(tnames,names(dists)),collapse="/")
    Finalres <- data.frame(tnames = dists) # build the df
    names(Finalres) <- rownames(Finalres) <- tnames # Name it

    if (prt>0) myprt("Final result:",Finalres)
    return(Finalres) # Last iteration

  } else {

    Finalres <- res
    Finalres[tnames,tnames] <- 0 # Set the diagonal to 0
    Finalres[is.na(Finalres)] <- dists # the previous assignment has set NAs, replae them by the dists values

    if (prt>0) myprt("Dataset before recursive call:",Finalres)
    return(hcl(Finalres,prt)) # we're not at end, recall ourselves with actual result

  }
}
```

---

Another idea by steps:

```
# To be allowed to add column later, don't know a better way than coercing to data.frame
d <- data.frame(D,stringsAsFactors=F) 

# 1) Get the shortest distance informations:
Ref <- which( d==min(d[d>0]), useNames=T, arr.ind=T ) 

# 2) Subset the original entry to remove thoose towns:
res <-d[-Ref[,1],-Ref[,1]]

# 3) Get the subset for the two nearest towns:
tmp <- d[-Ref[,1],Ref[,1]]

# 4) Get the vector of minimal distance from original dataset with the two town (row by row on tpm), didn't find a proper way to avoid apply
dists <- apply( tmp, 1, function(x) { x[x==min(x)] } )

dists <- dists <- tmp[ tmp == pmin( tmp[,1], tmp[,2] ) ]

# 5) Let's build the resulting matrix:
tnames <- paste(rownames(Ref),collapse="/") # Get the names of town to the new name
Finalres <- res
Finalres[tnames,tnames] <- 0 # Set the diagonal to 0
Finalres[is.na(Finalres)] <- dists # the previous assignment has set NAs, replae them by the dists values
```

Output:

```
> Finalres
       BA  FI  Na  RM TO/MI
BA      0 662 255 412   877
FI    662   0 468 268   295
Na    255 468   0 219   754
RM    412 268 219   0   564
TO/MI 877 295 754 564     0
```

And the output of each step:

```
> #Steps:
> 
> Ref
   row col
TO   6   3
MI   3   6
> res
    BA  FI  Na  RM
BA   0 662 255 412
FI 662   0 468 268
Na 255 468   0 219
RM 412 268 219   0
> tmp
    TO  MI
BA 996 877
FI 400 295
Na 869 754
RM 669 564
> dists
[1] 877 295 754 564
```

There's a lot of object copying here which can be avoided to save performance, I made it to have a better step by step view.

Comment: Upvoted: Thank you, this is also impressive. I will have a look at your code in detail :-)